# Related posts and custom meta_box?

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I am trying to code the ability to pick which posts should be included as related to the current post the user is editing. 
I have used @MikeSchinkel very helpfull post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85107/populating-meta-box-with-select-list-of-existing-posts-and-assigning-it-to-cust?answertab=active#tab-top), to include a list of posts in a metafield, I have then used [this patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/20156/post-template.multiselect_dropdown_pages.patch) to make the option multi select-able, I have also used the jquery chosen plugin to tidy the list up slightly. 
I am now thoroughly stuck on how to retrieve the values in my loop on the front end, i've tried the following amongst other things:

```
$intro = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'SELECT_POST_TYPE', true );
echo $intro;
var_dump( $_POST)
```

and this:

```
$intro = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $selected_post_id, true );
echo $intro;
var_dump($intro)
```

and this:

```
$intro = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'select_box', true );
echo $intro;
var_dump($intro)
```

the code to register the meta_box is the following:

```
class WPSE_85107 {
  var $FOR_POST_TYPE = 'question';
  var $SELECT_POST_TYPE = 'post';
  var $SELECT_POST_LABEL = 'Post';
  var $box_id;
  var $box_label;
  var $field_id;
  var $field_label;
  var $field_name;
  var $meta_key;
  function __construct() {
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin_init' ) );
  }
  function admin_init() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
    add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ), 10, 2 );
    $this->meta_key     = "_selected_{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";
    $this->box_id       = "select-{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}-metabox";
    $this->field_id     = "selected-{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";
    $this->field_name   = "selected_{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";
    $this->box_label    = __( "Select {$this->SELECT_POST_LABEL}", 'wpse-85107' );
    $this->field_label  = __( "Choose {$this->SELECT_POST_LABEL}", 'wpse-85107' );
  }
  function add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box(
      $this->box_id,
      $this->box_label,
      array( $this, 'select_box' ),
      $this->FOR_POST_TYPE,
      'side'
    );
  }
  function select_box( $post ) {
    $selected_post_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $this->meta_key, true );
    global $wp_post_types;
    $save_hierarchical = $wp_post_types[$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE]->hierarchical;
    $wp_post_types[$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE]->hierarchical = true;
    wp_dropdown_pages( array(
      'id' => $this->field_id,
      'name' => $this->field_name,
      'selected' => empty( $selected_post_id ) ? 0 : $selected_post_id,
      'post_type' => $this->SELECT_POST_TYPE,
      'show_option_none' => $this->field_label,
      'multiselect' => true,
      'class' => 'chzn-select'
    ));
    $wp_post_types[$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE]->hierarchical = $save_hierarchical;
  }
  function save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == $this->FOR_POST_TYPE && isset( $_POST[$this->field_name] ) ) {
      update_post_meta( $post_id, $this->meta_key, $_POST[$this->field_name] );
    }
  }
}
new WPSE_85107();
```

UPDATE: 
thanks to @matt_ here is the anwser this code goes in your front end loop-template:

```
 $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_selected_post', true); 

                        if ( ! $meta ):
                            echo  '';

                            else:?>
                        <a class="related_post" href="<?php echo get_permalink($meta); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($meta); ?></a>
                        <br/>
                    <?php  endif;
```

Comment: Please rework that code styling. Half didn't work out, half is not readable. Thanks

Comment: thank you for taking the time to look i have edited it...

Comment: Are you certain your meta is being saved? Try taking a look at the database. Not entirely sure what your question is.

Comment: @ghosttoast my question here is how do i retrieve the metabox value inside my custom post loop template file (archive-questions.php) on the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you will have to use

`$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_selected_post', true); 
echo $meta;`

The registered post type is hidden using the _ and it's name is defined at the line :

`$this->meta_key     = "_selected_{$this->SELECT_POST_TYPE}";`

Where SELECT_POST_TYPE is defined as 'post' at the line :

`var $SELECT_POST_TYPE = 'post';`

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes that does help I understand it now, I don't think it's doing quite what i want any way. It's just returning the post id not the title. On top of that i am also trying to retrive the post url... 
I'm building another function all is not going well though it's a sharp learning curve..

Comment: Then you just maybe have to use `echo get_the_title($meta);` where you need to display it.
Do you accept the response if it at least helps you? Thanks.

Comment: That works perfectly Thank you so much @matt_ I have been pulling my hair out for the last two days over this!!! 
I only have one problem left it only returns the first value i have selected from the multi select box do you know how to force it to retrive all the values selected or maybe register another select box in the same meta_box.

Comment: Hi.

If, in the line

`$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_selected_post', true); echo $meta;`

you remove the true, and you don't echo the result but put it in a `var_dump($meta);`, what result do you have?

Comment: @matt_ thanks for the help I have just registered 4 different buttons in the end. 
It works for now I spent to long on this allready! 
Thanks again for taking the time with this. 
Chris