# put saved metabox values back into fields and then display on the front end

Tags: custom-field, metabox, post-meta

i have a group of metaboxes which i finally are now saving but am struggling to get the saved values back into the input boxes they came from. so for example i have a meta field called link text and if i put 'link 1 text' in there and save I save it but it doesn't show back in the form.

the code i use for this is:

```
function home_callout_meta_box_cb($post) {
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field('home_callout_nonce', 'home_callout_meta_box_nonce');
    $values = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {

        $imagefield1[$i] = isset($values['imagefields'][$i]['image1']) ? esc_attr($values['imagefields'][$i]['image1'][0]): '';
        $imagefield2[$i] = isset($values['imagefields'][$i]['image2']) ? esc_attr($values['imagefields'][$i]['image2'][0]): '';

        $linktext[$i] = isset($values['linktext'][$i]) ? esc_attr($values['linktext'][$i][0]): '';
        $link[$i] = isset($values['link'][$i]) ? esc_attr($values['link'][$i][0]): '';


        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' image 1</strong></p>';
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="imagefields[' . $i . '][image1]" name="imagefields[' . $i . '][image1]" class="upload-url image_url" readonly="readonly" value="' . $imagefield1[$i] .'" />';
        echo '<input id="st_upload_button" class="st_upload_button button-secondary upload_image" type="button" name="upload_button" value="Upload" />';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' image 2</strong></p>';
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="imagefields[' . $i . '][image2]" name="imagefields[' . $i . '][image2]" class="upload-url image_url" readonly="readonly" value="' . $imagefield2[$i] .'" />';
        echo '<input id="st_upload_button" class="st_upload_button button-secondary upload_image" type="button" name="upload_button" value="Upload" />';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' link text</strong></p>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="linktext[' . $i . ']" name="linktext[' . $i . ']" value="' . $linktext[$i] . '" />';

        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' link</strong></p>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="link[' . $i . ']" name="link[' . $i . ']" value="' . $link[$i] . '" />';
        // var_dump($values['imagefields'][0]);
    }
}

function home_callout_save($post_id) {
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
    if(!isset($_POST['home_callout_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['home_callout_meta_box_nonce'], 'home_callout_nonce')) return;
    if(!current_user_can('edit_pages')) return;

    if(isset($_POST['imagefields'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'imagefields', $_POST['imagefields']);   
    }

    if(isset($_POST['linktext'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'linktext', $_POST['linktext']);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['link'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'link', $_POST['link']);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'home_callout_save');
```

I know the fields save because if i do a var_dump($values['linktext']);

this is the array that is returned:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(75) "a:3:{i:1;s:11:"link text 1";i:2;s:11:"Link 2 text";i:3;s:11:"Link 3 text";}" }
```

i am unsure how to get the saved values back into each field.

the other small question i have is to retreieve the values of each meta box on the front end would i use:

```
get_post_meta($post_id, 'linktext'][1]', true);
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the data out of the custom post type, assign it to a variable, then echo that value into the field when the page loads. If nothing else, that will make your code a lot more readable (and easier to troubleshoot) While it's not explicitly about what you are doing, you an see the exact method at work here ([WP Stackexchange Post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85107/populating-meta-box-with-select-list-of-existing-posts-and-assigning-it-to-cust)).

You may also find [Justin Tadlock's review of meta boxes](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/) at Smashing Magazine to be an enlightening read.

Finally, if you want shortcuts, a system like [WordPress Alchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) provides a good code library for rapid prototyping and execution, whereas something like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) takes a more GUI approach.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I know about acf/alchemy but am trying to do write it by hand as i would rather not rely on plugins. also i have other custom meta boxes that do work but because i am using a for loop i dont know how to get the values back into the fields. i could write out all 9 fields but thats bad practice and not dry so that is where im struggling

Answer (score 0):

So i finally have got the values appearing in the fields. I am not sure if im doing it in a nice way. but would happily appreciate some comments on how to do it better.

here is my code:

```
function home_callout_meta_box_cb($object, $post) {
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field('home_callout_nonce', 'home_callout_meta_box_nonce');
    $values = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {

        $imagefield1[$i] = isset($values['imagefields'][$i]['image1']) ? esc_attr($values['imagefields'][$i]['image1'][0]): '';
        $imagefield2[$i] = isset($values['imagefields'][$i]['image2']) ? esc_attr($values['imagefields'][$i]['image2'][0]): '';

        $linktext[$i] = isset($values['linktext'][$i]) ? esc_attr($values['linktext'][$i][0]): '';
        $link[$i] = isset($values['link'][$i]) ? esc_attr($values['link'][$i][0]): '';

        $linkText = get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'linktext', true );
        $linkUrl = get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'link', true );
        $image = get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'imagefields', true );



        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' image 1</strong></p>';
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="imagefields[' . $i . '][image1]" name="imagefields[' . $i . '][image1]" class="upload-url image_url" readonly="readonly" value="' . $image[$i]['image1'] .'" />';
        echo '<input id="st_upload_button" class="st_upload_button button-secondary upload_image" type="button" name="upload_button" value="Upload" />';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' image 2</strong></p>';
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="imagefields[' . $i . '][image2]" name="imagefields[' . $i . '][image2]" class="upload-url image_url" readonly="readonly" value="' . $image[$i]['image2'] .'" />';
        echo '<input id="st_upload_button" class="st_upload_button button-secondary upload_image" type="button" name="upload_button" value="Upload" />';
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' link text</strong></p>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="linktext[' . $i . ']" name="linktext[' . $i . ']" value="' . $linkText[$i] . '" />';

        echo '<p><strong>Call out box ' . $i .' link</strong></p>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="link[' . $i . ']" name="link[' . $i . ']" value="' . $linkUrl[$i] . '" />';

    }
}
```

what i did was i created some variables to retreive the meta data and it returned an array so i can use $i to get the correct one and echo that value in the field.

i feel that is a messy way so would appreciate some comments on how to do it better if there is a way?

Comment: That's actually much more readable than what you had before. You could optionally dispense with all the concatenated echoes. Close the PHP tag after your $image variable is declared then write up the HTML and inline the variables. Without going to a full on MVC format with template blades, you won't get a lot cleaner... plenty of us wish WordPress was MVC for this reason.

Comment: Thanks for the criticism very much appreciated. and thank you for pointing me in the right direction on how to fix my issue.